# A pexiderization of the sine addition law on semigroups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-and-monoids, functional-equations

Can we solve the follwing functional equation
$$f(xy)=g(x)h(y)+g(y)h(x)$$
on semigroups for unknown complex valued functions $f,g,h$ ?

Comment: for the clueless like me on what "pexiderization" refers to: https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe3108.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I corrected a typo on the right-hand-side of the equation in the OP, I'm unsure whether the left-hand-side has a typo, but the generalized sine addition law on semigroups is known in the form
$$g(xy)=g(x)h(y)+h(x)g(y),$$
so in terms of two unknown functions $g$ and $h$, generalizing
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y,$$
see [Ebanks - The sine addition and subtraction formulas on semigroups](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10474-021-01149-3) (2021).

Comment: Ebanks also has a later paper on the more general version the OP discusses: [Ebanks - Around the sine addition law and d'Alembert's equation on semigroups](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00025-021-01548-6).